# A proof that if $S \cap T = S$, then $S \subseteq T$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to prove the following:

> If $S \cap T = S$, then $S \subseteq T$.

I have no idea where to start. Here's what I have done so far:

Suppose $S$ and $T$ are two sets and assume the fact that $S \cap T = S$.

Let $(x \in S \cap T)$, then:

$(x \in S) \wedge (x \in T) ≡ (x \in S)$

I am stuck here. What should I do to get $S \subseteq T$?

Comment: What is"Proofing" ?

Comment: Hint: $S\subseteq T$ means $\forall x: x\in S\implies x\in T$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your proof, you have to show $S \subseteq T$ given that $S \cap T = S$. In order to show $S \subseteq T$, we have to show that every element in $S$ is also an element in $T$.

With that said, suppose $x \in S$. We have to show $x \in T$. This will prove $S \subseteq T$ since we are picking an arbitrary $x$.

Now, since $x \in S$ and $S = S \cap  T $, we have $x \in S \cap T$. Next, use your definition for what $x \in S \cap T$ means to finish it off.

Comment: Suppose $x∈S$. Since $S∩T = S$, then $x∈S∩T$. By definition, this means $(x∈S) Λ (x∈T)$. Then, x∈T, which implies $S⊆T$

Comment: Is that a proper proof?

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that $S \subseteq T$ means that $x \in S$ implies $x \in T$. So in your proof you start by supposing $x \in S$, and then use the assumption that $S \cap T = S$ to show that $x \in T$. Why might this be the case? To get you started, notice that we have $x \in S \cap T$ since $S \cap T = S$. Now you can use the definition of $S \cap T$ to see that we must have $x \in T$.

Comment: umm I still don't get it. S∩T means that {x: (x ∈ S) Λ (x ∈ T)}. I mean like it is clear that we must have x ∈ T from here. But how to express such idea?

Comment: So $x \in S \cap T$ _implies_ that $x \in T$.

Answer (score 0):

We know $S \cap T \subset T$ and $S \cap T =S$ so $S \subset T$.